# Exchange 2003/Outlook 2010 no rules but messages still auto-ccing

Tags: exchange, outlook

In our office we have an Exchange 2003 server, and clients using Outlook 2010.

Every time user A receives an e-mail, it gets automatically cc-ed to user B. (Note: this rule is applied regardless of whether A is logged on.) I have used MFCMAPI on the server to delete all messages in user A's Inbox's Associated Contents Table of class IPM.Rule.Message, and now when user A uses Outlook, she cannot see any rules. However, the messages are still being auto-cced.

(Some background information: It's very likely that a rule used to exist for this purpose, as this behaviour used to be desirable. User A is the only user whose messages are auto-cced to user B, and user B is the only user who gets user A's mail auto-cced.)

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening and how to fix it, short of creating a new mailbox for user A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this cc rules at different locations. Like you mentioned a user can create himself rules using outlook. Also its possible to create such a behaviour via configuration on the server side.

1. Check for local rules.
2. Check for server side rules / redirects (You will have to check the user A configuration in the active directory)
3. If there are no rules on the server side try to create a new local outlook profile. (System settings --> E-mail, you dont have to delete the old profile just keep it in case there is no change in behaviour)
4. If 1-3 fail the fastest way would be to remove user A (including the mail box) and then recreate the user.

Comment: In fact there were server side rules, which I removed via Active Directory Users and Computers. (I was not even aware that such things were possible.) Problem solved - thank you.

Comment: Im used to do that a lot because a lot of users dont know how to use outlook, so they mailed me every time they wanted to go on vacation :P.